# Dynamically Converting strings into Class Name in same namespace Type.GetType() returning null

Tags: c#, type-conversion, generic-programming

I have a `List` of `strings` which contains `UserControl` classes. I wish to pass that `List` to a `foreach()` loop and create an `object` of each `class` in the `List`

```
 List<string> MyUserControlList= new List<string>();
            Permissions.Add("Profile_UC");
            Permissions.Add("Bio_UC");

foreach(var Information in MyUserControlList)
            {

                //Getting Usercontrol class name
                Type uc1 = Type.GetType(Information); 

               // Type uc1 = Type.GetType("Tab_Control_and_User_Control_test."+Permission,Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name);

                //Creating instance of relative user control class
                Object MyUserControlObject = Activator.CreateInstance(uc1);                
                //rest of my logic

            }
```

I searched and find that its kind of an assembly issue, but I didn't find any good resource to point out it in a dynamic way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please Provide full path of your object means with namespace 
Like

```
      String p = "ConsoleApplication1.Profile_UC";
 Type uc1 = Type.GetType(p);
```